# Characteristic function of a Poisson law

Tags: characteristic-functions, poisson-distribution

I would like to show that
$$ \bigg(e^{itc}  - 1 - \frac{it c}{1+ c^2} \bigg) \frac{1+ c^2}{c^2} G(c) - G(c-\delta)$$

is the characteristic function of a poisson distribution.

This follows from the claim in Komogorov's book [Limit distributions for sum of independent random variables]

[image]

The characteristic function of a poisson $X \sim$ Poi($\lambda$)
$$\phi_{X}(t) = \Bbb{E}[e^{it X}] = \exp\{\lambda(e^{it} - 1)\}$$

If we multiply $X$ by $\alpha$ we obtain:

$$\phi_{\alpha X}(t) = \Bbb{E}[e^{it\alpha X}] = \exp\{\lambda(e^{i\alpha t} - 1)\}$$

So I guess that $\alpha  = c $. I would also guess that $\lambda = \frac{1+ c^2}{c^2} G(c) - G(c-\delta)$ but that seems wrong since it misses  the term $\frac{it c}{1+ c^2}$ .

Comment: hmm...what is actually meant by "left", just the term in brackets? could you maybe add a link or reference to this, just for the sake of completeness

Comment: Well, I can only say that the book is  Limit distributions for sum of independent random variables written by Kolmogorov and Gnedenko https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Limit_distributions_for_sums_of_independ.html?id=rYsZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a Poisson type random variable i.e. for $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $\lambda>0$

$$P\{X=x_0+k\cdot h\}=\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

its characteristic function is given by

$$\varphi_X(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{it(x_0+kh)}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}=e^{itx_0}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{it(kh)}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}=e^{ix_0t}e^{\lambda(e^{ith}-1)}$$